# Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri); will open web page on server or client side?

Tags: jsf, client-server

I have a JSF application and when user click on button I want to open a web page.
`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);` probably opens a web page on server side,
how to do it on client side?

when i try Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri); it works, but maybe its because I open the JSF application on localhost so I dont know if the opened uri is on server side or client side.

In the specification for getDesktop() its written:

```
getDesktop() 
Returns the Desktop instance of the current browser context.
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you don't have a desktop client? You only have a JSF application, and you want the page in the browser to change after clicking a button (in the browser) ?

Comment: I have just JSF application, and I want just when the client open the JSF application and when he clicks on the button(in the browser in the JSF application), to open new page in the browser on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a simple link (and perhaps style it as a button):

```
<h:outputLink href="otherpage.jsf" target="_blank" />
```

If you insist on a button, there is a way to do this with [javascript](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200605/using_javascript_instead_of_target_to_open_new_windows/), but I'd recommend against it.

When developing web applications, forget about `java.awt.*` and `javax.swing.*` - they are not to be used in web application development (unless you create applets)

Comment: and how to see if Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri); will open web page on client side or server side cause Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri); is much more useful for me? any idea Bozho?

Comment: Dektop.getDesktop() won't work on client side at all. When developing webapps forget about that (and related) classes.

Comment: hm...then I dont understand really why in the specification getDesktop() is defined like: 
Returns the Desktop instance of the >>>current<<< browser context. Current like client current browser or what?

Comment: if you use it in Applet, then this makes sense ;) But you aren't using an applet.

Comment: Ok you are right:) So from JSF java bean is it possible to open web page on client side? :)

Comment: no, apart from the way I showed - using HTML/javascript techniques. (the `<h:outputLink>` is translated to `<a href=..`)